# How to override the default reducer implementation for an entity in ngrx/data

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, angular-ngrx-data, ngrx-data

I am trying to do the pagination using ngrx/data. In the initial request, the page size is 10 and pageNumber is 1. When I am triggering the second request with page size 10 and page number 2. It is truncating the older value and saving the values received from the second API response.

I want to append the values received from the second API response in the data store(without losing the initial values). For that, I am guessing maybe override the default reducer might help.

I checked the official docs, but there is not that much helpful. If I get small example, it will be great.